# Are transactions possible when setting up/ sync wallet Qt2

Tags: transactions, wallet, blockchain

Hi any help really appreciated..

About 12 months ago I purchased some bit coins from 2 different merchants and began to sync my wallet on Qt 2. Frustrated with tedious progress I put the project on hold, and now have continued to sync, which is still only 88% complete.

My question and dilemma is this. I can't recall in the set up process if I was required to send coins to my own wallet, there are 3 transactions showing 2 received and one sent.. I don't remember if I actually sent coins to someone back then when I was going to purchase a product, I seem to recall the coins I was going to send him somehow weren't yet  in my out of sync wallet…

Is it possible to be sending coins before the wallet is synced ?

So if a new, out of sync wallet is showing coins as having been sent to 
an address, could that be to my own wallet due to the set up process ?
that address is listed in the "sent to' tab is there a way to check if its me or where it went ?
Cheers,

Tim